# Passing Microsoft Graph api calls from Spring Boot backend to Angular

Tags: java, angular, microsoft-graph-api

My Authorization Client: Angular, Resource Server: Java Spring Boot, Authorization Server: Azure Active Directory

I am getting an access token from my Angular client, passing it to my back end Spring resource server.
The backend is using an OBO flow to request another token on behalf of the user, and access Microsoft Graph api.

Now that I have the methods and controllers set up, the /me api call for graph returns user data.

I have made the service call setup in Angular to call the api, but I don't believe Microsoft Graph returns JSON response back to the user.

What is the correct way to retrieve the user data back into angular, so that I can display the information from the api call.

**Java**

GraphAPICOntroler.java

import com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.User;

[image]

**Angular**

graph.service.ts

import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';

[image]

**main. component.ts**

```
    export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  name: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(
    private graphService: GraphService
  ) {
  }

 ngOnInit() {

  this.name = this.getUser();

  }

  public getUser(){
      this.graphService.getUser().subscribe(
        response => {
          this.name = response;
        });
    
  }
}
```

Comment: From the back end you already got the user data, and you are now trying to pass it to front end. Am I correct?